# Emacs Org-mode: Hiding / Ignoring Scheduled Items in Global Agenda View

Tags: regex, emacs, org-mode

I've included the following in my init.el file:

```
(setq org-agenda-todo-ignore-scheduled 'all)
(setq org-agenda-tags-todo-honor-ignore-options t)
```

But unfortunately, when I create my global agenda using,

```
C-a a
```

the items that are scheduled, in the form,

```
* TODO Task to Complete
  SCHEDULED: <2014-06-03 Tue>
```

continue to show up. Everything seems to be working for the Global list of TODO items, created with:

```
C-a t
```

My three questions are:

1. What can I included in my init.el file to, but default using C-a a, to exclude SCHEDULED items?
2. Assuming that's possible, what can I do to make them re-appear and / or disappear while in the agenda view? For example, I can [do all sorts of filtering](http://orgmode.org/manual/Filtering_002flimiting-agenda-items.html) based on tags, properties, and regexp. In short, I'd like to be able to toggle their inclusion in my global agenda view.
3. Assuming neither 1 nor 2 are possible, what custom agenda commands could I use to exclude SCHEDULED items?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `(org-agenda-entry-types '(:deadline)) ;; this entry excludes :scheduled`  That is what you would put inside your `org-agenda-custom-commands`.  Outside of `org-agenda-custom-commands`, you would put a `setq` in front of `org-agenda-entry-types`.  I'll let other forum participants handle your other questions.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @lawlist. I can confirm that this definitely works. I'm currently using SCHEDULED as my SOMEDAY identifier / bucket for future tasks. Now I just need to figure out how to show those entries when I want to. I have no doubt that this can be accomplished with the custom agenda views. For anyone else who is curious, just **M-x describe-variable RET org-agenda-entry-types**!

Comment: One method would be to create your own `org-agenda-custom-commands` and use `(org-agenda-entry-types '(:scheduled))` to reveal those when you want.

Comment: I'm making this next comment a separate comment because it is important, but perhaps not what you need at this time.  For more specific targeting of what to include or exclude, some occasions may justify using something like this when creating your own `org-agenda-custom-commands`:  `(org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'regexp "\\* Active\\|\\* Next Action"))` or something like this:  `(org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notregexp "\\* Reference"))`